# Change of input value with state in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am having 3 text boxes in which users enter values alongwith that I have 3 sliders for which the value is set based on calculation of percentage from the entered values. My problem is I also want to change the text box values based on calculation formulas. So the text box I want them to reflect values with calculation as the slider values change plus user can also type in values.For eg for first textbox I want to calculate value inside with (total-b-c). So with changes in slider values of percentages the values in textboxes should also change. I am unable to do that now-

Here is some supporting code for the same-

```
const [userValues, setUserValues] = useState({
    a: '0',
    b: '0',
    c: '0',
    
    
  });
const handleInputChange = (event) =>{
   setUserValues({ ...userValues, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    
}
```

**Textboxes**-

```
  <div className="container1">
      
        <div className="headingsleft">Enter number of <br></br> invoices</div>
        <div>
        <h4 style={{fontWeight:500, marginLeft:30,fontSize:19}}>a Invoices</h4>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
       <TextField  label="p.a." type="number" name="a" size="small"  className={classes.root}  inputProps={{ min: "0" }}  variant="outlined"  value={userValues.nonedinumber}  onChange={handleInputChange} required error={userValues.a=== ""}   helperText={userValues.a=== "" ? 'Required' : ' '}  ></TextField> 
      
      
         </div>
          
        <div>
        <h4 className="headings">b Invoices</h4>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <TextField label="p.a." type="number" name="b" size="small" className={classes.root}  inputProps={{ min: "0" }} variant="outlined" value={userValues.b} onChange={handleInputChange} required error={userValues.b=== ""}   helperText={userValues.b=== "" ? 'Required' : ' '}/> 
        </div>


        <div>
        <h4 style={{fontWeight:500, marginLeft:30,fontSize:19}}>cInvoices</h4>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <TextField label="p.a." type="number" name="c" size="small" className={classes.root} inputProps={{ min: "0" }}  variant="outlined" value={userValues.c} onChange={handleInputChange} required error={userValues.c=== ""}   helperText={userValues.c=== "" ? 'Required' : ' '}/> 
        </div>


       
        <div>
        <h4 style={{fontWeight:500, marginLeft:30,fontSize:19}}>Total Invoices</h4>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <TextField label="p.a." type="number" size="small" id="total" value={total} disabled variant="outlined"  /> 
        </div>
       
      
       
      </div>
```

**code for the slider-**

```
const Inputaftercalculate = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <div>
              <div className="container2">

              <div className="headingsleft">Percentage Distribution 
           
</div>

            <div >
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Typography   className={classes.slider}  id="discrete-slider-always" gutterBottom>

            </Typography>
            <Slider 
            defaultValue={20}
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
            step={10}
            marks={marks}
            valueLabelDisplay="on"
            value={props.a}
            disabled
            />
            </div>

            <div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Typography className={classes.slider}  id="discrete-slider-always" gutterBottom>

            </Typography>
            <Slider
            defaultValue={20}
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
            step={10}
            marks={marks}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            value={props.b}
            />
            </div>

            <div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Typography className={classes.slider}  id="discrete-slider-always" gutterBottom>

            </Typography>
            <Slider
            defaultValue={1}
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
            step={10}
            marks={marks}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            value={props.c}
            />
            </div>


</div>
        </div>
```

How can I make the input textboxes adjust inside values based on changes in slider values and also let users input in the textbox whenever they need to change values?

Answer (score 1):

First you got get the value and it respective key  from the event, then expand it and finally assign the value to the respective key name as shown bellow.

`const handleInputChange = e => { const {name, value} = e.target;  handleInputChange({ ...userValues, [name]: value, }) }`